# void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:)

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, webview, ios6.1

I am loading my webview with running image(banner) while continuously load webview . but sometimes i got warning of

> void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) 
>   failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

and hanged for some times.

webview loading data in the form of HTML (Not javascript in HTMl).

please suggest me, how to handle this warning .

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**I think the problem is solved with the update from today (iOS 6.1 SDK) and I also think it is related to the simulator. I think it is about interfering outgoing requests from skpaymenttransaction and other UIWebView... I am not sure about anything, however...**

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me

```
 - (void) dealloc
 {
 if(webView){
 [webView stopLoading];
 webView.delegate = nil;
 }
 }
```